# Is it bad to run a thread for longer period (+30mins) in Android?

Tags: android

I'm running a thread from a service where i'm listening for changers in the acceleronometer every 3 seconds. So i run the listener in a while loop with Thread.sleep(3000). But it tends to work with shorter duration. But in longer run it seems to get crash the whole application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thread.sleep(3000) is not a good option user timer task or other available option............

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113701/long-running-android-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `AsyncTask`, and problem of crashing threads fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using an IntentService instead, It is the same thing as a service except that it will run off of the main UI thread. Otherwise there should not be a problem that i know of. Services are suposed to be long running.

Answer (score 0):

you should use alarm for the time tracking and brodcast reciever.